# How to display special symbols in Gtk.Label?

Tags: unicode, gtk, label, vala

I am writing an Instagram client for Ubuntu in Vala. And I'm using `Gtk.Label`s to display post title, comments etc. Problem is, sometimes received data contains special symbols like smiles etc. And currently they are displayed incorrectly, like in the picture (these squares containing 6 hex numbers):

[image]

I guess that's not the problem of my application because I've seen such behavior in other apps (for example, Pantheon Files). But anyway, this is not the way I want my program to behave, I want these symbols to be displayed correctly.

So, my question is: is it possible to achieve the behavior I want? And if it is possible, then how?

Comment: I'm guessing it's an issue with the font you're using... the box character shows that your text is being decoded correctly, but that the glyph isn't there. What do other apps show?

Comment: @andlabs I didn't change the font, it's the default one. Pantheon Files, for example, behaves the same way, if, for example, there are files inside current folder with such filenames

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of a program that works correctly? I'm suggesting that the default font does not have those glyphs...

Comment: Those are emoji. Your font simply doesn't contain them.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a font issue.

Comment: It seems to be a real fonts issue. I'll try to use another font that contains emojis then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was indeed an issue with the font I'm using. I just installed `ttf-ancient-fonts` package (according to the https://www.kirsle.net/blog/entry/make-emoji-work-in-linux) and now it is working.